# Ultraproduct with no long descending sequence

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, model-theory

I have a countably infinite well-ordered structure $M$ (over a countable language if it helps), and an uncountable regular cardinal $κ$, and I wanted to construct an elementarily equivalent structure with certain properties. I could not find a way to control the model that the compactness theorem gives, so I thought of following the proof of the compactness theorem based on ultraproducts.

Let $C$ be the collection of finite subsets of $κ$ and let $F = \{ \{ S : S \in C \land S \supseteq I \} : I \in C \}$. Then $F$ is closed under binary intersection, and hence can be extended to an ultrafilter $U$. Let $(c_i)_{i \in κ}$ be distinct constant symbols that are not in the language of $M$. For each $I \in C$ let $M_I$ be $M$ extended by interpreting $(c_i)_{i \in I}$ as the sequence of the first $\#(I)$ elements in $M$. Let $N$ be the ultraproduct $\prod_{I \in C} M_I / U$. Then for any $i,j \in κ$ such that $i < j$, we have $M_S \vDash c_i < c_j$ for every $S \in C$ such that $S \supseteq \{i,j\}$, and hence $N \vDash c_i < c_j$.

Now I would also like $N$ to have no decreasing sequence of length $κ$, but I do not know whether that can be ensured by some suitable choice of $U$. So my questions are:

1. Is there some choice of $U$ such that $N$ has no decreasing sequence of length $κ$?

   a. If so, is there some choice of $U$ such that $N$ has no uncountable decreasing sequence?

   b. If not, what is the smallest $κ$ such that there is a structure $M$ where every choice of $U$ makes $N$ have a decreasing sequence of length $κ$?

My random guess is that (1) is true and (1b) is false but I can't even guess about (1a).

I tried searching for various types of ultrafilters. I found out that if there is a countably-complete ultrafilter on $κ$, then $κ$ must be a measurable cardinal, and for such $κ$ this proves the strong result that $N$ is well-ordered. But I would like to know if the weaker (1a) for arbitrary $κ$ can be answered in ZFC alone. Similarly I hope that ZFC is enough to settle my other questions.

Finally, I am curious to know if the answers change if $κ$ is not regular.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I'm hoping you might have plenty to say on this. Now you know why I was commenting on your old answer just now. =)

Comment: I was on the phone for a while... sorry :P

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for some sort of strong- or even supercompactness, but then (1) it won't work very well with countable ordinals because they are far too small; and (2) the ultrapower of a well-ordered set by a $\sigma$-closed ultrafilter is always well-ordered again. So perhaps the solution is actually to look at some model theoretic properties of ultrafilters, like regularity and so on, and then assume something about cardinal invariants related to various combinatorial properties of them (e.g. $\frak p,t$ and so on). But this is beyond the scope of my brain, so I can't say more

Comment: @AsafKaragila: No hurry. But I don't understand what you mean about countable ordinals. I restrict $κ$ to be an uncountable cardinal. I also don't know anything about cardinal invariants, any suggested resource where I can read about them?

Comment: Andreas Blass wrote a chapter for the Handbook of Set Theory. You might also want to consider, as it deals with ultrafilters, to look at the works of Maryanthe Malliaris (especially her collaborations with Saharon Shelah, and related works); and perhaps also the masters thesis of Giuseppe Moranarocca, which you can [find here](http://www.logicatorino.altervista.org/matteo_viale/tesi-moranarocca.pdf) includes a suitable exposition about these things (specifically, $\frak p$ and $\frak t$).

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I think the result of Malliaris and Shelah (i.e. $\mathfrak{p} = \mathfrak{t}$) shows that "certain types of partial orders" are "as complicated" relative to the Keisler order as "linear orders". So, I think if OP looks there, he/she might be looking at a much more complicated result than necessary.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: And by "certain types of partial orders" I mean theories which are $SOP_3$.

Comment: This is a partial answer: If $D$ is a regular ultrafiler, then we have that $\prod_D M_i$ is always at least $\aleph_1 -$saturated. I believe this results can be found in Chapter 6 of Chang and Keisler. 

Now, this quickly implies that you have an uncountable infinitely descending chain, and so $(1a)$ is false. You always get an uncountable decreasing chain. Thus, $(1b)$ is true with $\kappa = \aleph_1$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Thanks for your references; I'll take a look.

Comment: @KyleGannon: Are you saying that for some regular $κ > ω$ **every** choice of $U$ is regular? If not, then you can't quickly disprove (1a). Sorry if I'm missing something simple.

Comment: @user21820: You are correct. I wasn't thinking properly. In general, questions about nonregular ultrafilters are hard. The only method I know of where one can construct a non-regular ultrafilter over $\omega_2$ is using large cardinal axioms. Here's a [link](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1979-249-01/S0002-9947-1979-0526312-2/S0002-9947-1979-0526312-2.pdf)  that might be of interest.

Comment: @KyleGannon: Ok thanks for the link! I've no experience at all but, this question seems to have some intrinsic structure that is more than the ultrafilter structure, because trying to prove non-existence of longer decreasing sequences is supposed to be easier, but nothing in the ultrafilter structure seems to matter past a countable sequence. In particular an ultrafilter being countably complete is supposed to be easier than being $κ$-complete for $κ > ω_1$, so the 'obvious' way to obtain a contradiction is also obviously wrong.

Comment: Why is your description of the ultraproduct so complicated? Can you explain why you're restricting to ultrafilters extending $F$ and expanding the copies of $M$ by constants, instead of considering all ultrapowers of $M$?

Comment: @AlexKruckman: As I said in my first paragraph, I want a structure that has an ascending sequence of length $κ$. For that alone it suffices to use the compactness theorem, but then I get a model that I have no control over. That is why I tried unravelling the proof of compactness theorem via ultraproducts, which needs each finite set of inequalities on the $κ$ new constants to be satisfied by something elementarily equivalent to $M$, and uses an ultrafilter extending $F$.

Comment: Compactness is generally a brandished sword. This is one of the reasons set theorists resort to different tools like forcing and inner models.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I see. But inner models mainly apply to set theories right?

Comment: Yes yes, definitely. I didn't suggest either these techniques are useful elsewhere. I merely remarked that compactness is hardly controllable. Which is why set theorists prefer finer techniques. And also bragged that we *have* these techniques in set theory! WOOOOOO! :-D

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Hahaha... just curious, do you know if NFU can handle inner models too?

Comment: Not the slightest clue, actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the comments (but not in the question), you clarify that you want the ultrapower to have an increasing sequence of length $\kappa$, but no decreasing sequence of length $\kappa$. I don't know if this is possible (for a general ultrapower of a well-order), but I'll explain why it seems hard. The following theorem is from Keisler's paper *Ultraproducts which are not saturated*.

**Theorem:** Let $M$ be a structure, and let $U$ be a regular ultrafilter on $\kappa$. Let $\Sigma$ be a set of formulas such that $|\Sigma| = \kappa$ and every finite subset of $\Sigma$ is satisfiable in $M$. Then $\Sigma$ is satisfiable in $M^\kappa/U$.

**Proof:** Since $U$ is regular, there is some set $X\subseteq U$ such that $|X| = \kappa$, and for all $\alpha\in \kappa$, $X_\alpha = \{S\in X\mid \alpha\in S\}$ is a finite subset of $X$. Let $h\colon \Sigma\to X$ be a bijection. For all $\alpha$, let $\Sigma_\alpha = h^{-1}(X_\alpha)$. Since $\Sigma_\alpha$ is finite, it is satisfiable in $M$.

To show that $\Sigma$ is satisfiable in $M^\kappa/U$, we have to assign the variables used in $\Sigma$ to element of $M^\kappa/U$, i.e. for each $\alpha\in \kappa$, we have to assign them to elements of $M_\alpha$, the copy of $M$ indexed by $\alpha$ in the product. In each $M_\alpha$, do this so that the variables used in $\Sigma_\alpha$ are assigned to elements satisfying $\Sigma_\alpha$, and assign the other variables arbitrarily. Now, with this variable assignment, for each $\varphi\in \Sigma$, $\{\alpha\in \kappa\mid M_\alpha \models \varphi\}\supseteq \{\alpha\in \kappa\mid \varphi\in \Sigma_\alpha\} = \{\alpha\in \kappa\mid h(\varphi)\in X_\alpha\} = h(\varphi) \in X\subseteq U$, so $M^\kappa/U$ satisfies $\Sigma$. $\square$

As a consequence, if $M$ is *any* infinite linear order and $U$ is a regular ultrafilter on $\kappa$, then the ultrapower $M^\kappa/U$ has increasing *and* descreasing sequences of length $\kappa$. To see this, introduce variables $(x_\alpha)_{\alpha<\kappa}$, and let $\Sigma = \{x_\alpha<x_\beta\mid \alpha<\beta<\kappa\}$ or $\{x_\alpha>x_\beta\mid \alpha<\beta<\kappa\}$.

This symmetry between increasing and decreasing sequences, and the difficulty of coming up with non-regular ultrafilters makes me think that your desired construction will be difficult to accomplish, if not impossible.

**Edit:** As noted in the comments below, the theorem really just generalizes the construction given in the question to arbitrary sets of formulas of size $\kappa$ and arbitrary regular ultrafilters.

If you're only interested in ultrafilters $U$ on $C$ the set of all finite subsets of $\kappa$ extending the set $F$ given in the question, then your question is answered. Let $X_\alpha = \{S\in C\mid \{\alpha\}\subseteq S\}$, and let $X = \{X_\alpha\mid \alpha < \kappa\}\subseteq F$. This $X$ witnesses regularity of any ultrafilter $U$ extending $F$. So there is no ultrafilter $U$ on $C$ extending $F$, such that the ultrapower has no decreasing sequence of length $\kappa$. The choice of $\kappa$ is irrelevant.

Of course, there may still be ultrapowers of $M$ by non-regular ultrafilters or ultrafilters on sets of size $<\kappa$ such that $M$ has an increasing sequence of length $\kappa$ but no decreasing sequence of length $\kappa$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Just to address your first sentence, I did say so in my question, when I said $N \vDash c_i < c_j$ for any $i,j \in κ$ such that $i < j$, and then went on to say "I would also like $N$ to have no ...". So I guess your answer extends Kyle's comment. Hmm... wait a moment, after reading your answer, I realize that my $N$ with new constants forgotten is exactly the same structure as if I assign $(c_i)_{i \in I}$ to a **decreasing** (instead of increasing) sequence in each $M_I$. This works for any ultrafilter extending $F$, even if it is not regular! Is this correct?

Comment: Oh, yes, good observation. Your construction is actually very closely related to the proof given in my answer, which just generalizes this construction to arbitrary regular ultrafilters. Keisler has a survey paper [here](http://www.math.wisc.edu/~keisler/ultraproducts-web-final.pdf) in which he claims (Prop 9.2 (i)) that every ultrafilter extending your $F$ is regular, but I don't see how to prove this off-hand.

Comment: I see. That's interesting. So I suppose that for my specific case of linear ordering I do not need regularity, but in general we would? And that it so happens (according to Keisler) that any ultrafilter extending $F$ must be regular?

Comment: Wait I don't think it has anything to do with the linear ordering. I think that any ultrafilter extending $F$ already satisfies your theorem, and so does any regular ultrafilter. It's just 'coincidental' that the former is actually of the latter sort.

Comment: Well, to do your construction, you're using the fact that the ultrafilter you've picked extends $F$, and if you look at how the proof works, you're essentially using regularity. This line of thinking makes me realize that Keisler's claim is really easy: Our ultrafilter $U$ is on $C$ the set of all finite subsets of $\kappa$. Let $X_\alpha = \{S\in C\mid \{\alpha\}\in S\}$, and let $X = \{X_\alpha\mid \alpha < \kappa\}$. This witnesses regularity.

Comment: Could add it to your answer, so that I can accept it, since it fully resolves my question? (1) is false and (1b) is true, and it does not matter whether $κ$ is regular. I mean, now parts of your first and last paragraphs are no longer needed. =)